# Create a form that adds observations to existing table using shiny R

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I'm using RStudio 0.98.953 and R 3.1.0 on a PC with Windows 8.1.

I am trying to use shiny in R to create a form for many users that will store their typed information by adding to an existing, initially empty table. I have seen a couple of questions already posted on the subject, but the answers were not written up clearly.

I want any user to be able to add to the table using the multiple *textInput* fields and later call upon this table to make edits, updates, and even make graphs of this information. Specifically, I want the input to go to two places: a **dataTableOutput** for display on the user's screen and a **csv** file for me to access at any point. Instead, what is happening is that the **dataTableOutput** is only displaying one entry (the latest one) at a time. And there is nothing being written to a csv file. I have made numerous entries to test it and it always fails. I have tried using observe and isolate around the code that creates the user's data.table.  I have tried an if statement similar to `if(input$Submit > 0) { ...` to use the submit button, but the submit button seems to work fine without this code.

This is my code:

server.R

```
library(data.table)

# first I initialize an empty data table with all of the potential fields 
# I want for each future record. There are more fields initially set than my user 
# will start off with.

ir <- data.table(X = "", Y = "", Z = "", W = "", V = "", U = "")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

# this is a reactive data.table that takes inputs from the UI (X, Y, and Z).

obs <- reactive({

        data.table(X = input$X, Y = input$Y, 
                         Z = input$Z)
})

# this generates a table of the information for the user to see. It should show
# their record being added to a list that is continuously being added to. 

output$table <- renderDataTable({

    rbind(ir, obs())

    })

# take the latest entry, add it to the running table, and write to a csv.

reactive({
        rbind(ir, obs())
        write.csv(ir, file = "C:/Users/Geo/Documents/ideaTracker/data/ideaRecords.csv")
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("Tracker",

# some UI code is not shown since it only defines the layout of other pages in the app.

sidebarPanel(

    # This defines the 'X' input

    dateInput("X", label = h4("Date"), value = as.character(Sys.Date()), 
                          format = "mm/dd/yy"),

    # defines the 'Y' input

    textInput("Y", h4("Name"),
                          value = "Joe Employee"),

    # and the 'Z' input

    textInput("Z", h4("Enter Information Here"), value = ""),

    submitButton("Submit")
            ),

    mainPanel(

        # displays the information entered by the user and should show the 
        # running list with all previous entries.

        dataTableOutput("table"),

    )
```

I think many other people can benefit from having this problem (and answer, hopefully) well documented.